# I have an old HTC Sense and i am having problems getting market to open or even updating to google play store.

Tags: google-play-store

I have an old HTC Sense Android, running 2.3.4, I'm not new to this scene, i currently have a galaxy S6 Active and a S8+, but im still learning, ANYWAY this phone doesnt have service, just wifi, i was bored and It has market, but won't connect. Did they make updates to install google play store, ?? Does the Android market even still exist..?? I appreciate any help.       - D.W.O 
I have just seen that in settings it says 2.3.4 but somewhere else i saw 2.3.6...also this device is stock, i have no clue about rooting...would like to learn

Comment: FYI, "HTC Sense" is the name of HTC's Android skin. It's not the model of the phone.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Dan, i just happen to see the skin version is like 2.1 i believe. Anyway phone screen shattered after posting this, so moving on....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Android Market" has been renamed to "Google Play Store" long ago. Afraid Google also changed the API since and deprecated the old one, so you won't be able to use this "ancient" version anymore.

For an alternative, you could try [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/), an open source Android "market" which should still work with "ancient versions". There you'd also find apps like [Yalp Store](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.github.yeriomin.yalpstore/), which would allow you accessing Play Store.

Comment: Thanks man, i knew about Fdroid, but thought i had seen somewhere, that play store would run on older market devices...i appreciate your help. Funny end note though, rite after i posted this, my wife knocked phone off table...screen cracked to hell....still useable, but barely.

Comment: Sad to read. A case for our [broken-screen tag-wiki](/tags/broken-screen/info) then. Take a special look at the "second use" section.

Comment: Yeah...actually that's the reason i started this whole mess...i was going to use as a "project" security cam and try apps like Alfred. Now, i have uncovered more than i knew existed, i believe i am an Android addict...lol

Comment: *LOL* Enjoy your addiction then. I live with that for 8 years now #D

Comment: Hey Izzy, if you have time, as i know you are pretty busy, by the looks of ur profile, i have a couple questions that would probably be easily answered by you, about an earlier android running "Froyo" i believe. I checked ur other sites, but did not see how to contact you, besides twitter, and i don't really screw around with twitter...i would just leave my email, but am kinda scared to do so, just because everyone on this site os a badass...thanks man.

Comment: @MurphyzLaw that doesn't really belong here, but my Android site also offers Mastodon – and a mail address in its imprint.